# Implementar método abstracto

Tags: php

Tengo una clase Empleado con una función abstracta declarada y otra clase Comerciante que hereda, donde en el constructor intento utilizar el método abstracto que debe realizar un calculo y asignarle el resultado al sueldo del Comerciante.

El caso es que me da error "undefined function", no logro ver cual es el error por mas evidente que parezca y por qué sucede. Agradezco cualquier ayuda, gracias.

```
       <?php

          abstract class Empleado {
             const SUELDO = 1200;
             abstract function calculaSueldo();
             abstract function mostrarInfo();
          }

          class Comerciante extends Empleado{

           private $nombre;
           private $apellido;
           private $sueldo;
           private $horasExtra;
           const BONIFICACION = 600;
   
  
           function __construct($nombre, $apellido, $horasExtra) {

             $this->nombre = $nombre;
             $this->apellido = $apellido;
             $this->horasExtra = $horasExtra;
             $this->sueldo = calculaSueldo();     //-------> ERROR

           }

           function calculaSueldo() {
             $sueldototal =  Empleado::SUELDO + (self::$horasExtra * 20) + self::BONIFICACION;
             return $sueldototal;
           }

           function mostrarInfo(){
            $info = "<h2>Información del empleado:</h2>";
            $info.= "<br/> Nombre: ".$this->nombre;
            $info.= "<br/> Apellido: ".$this->apellido;
            $info.= "<br/> Extras: ".$this->horasExtra;
            $info.= "<br/> Sueldo:" .$this->sueldo;           
         
            return $info; 
          }

}
?>
```

La traza de error es:

```
        ERROR: 
       Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function calculaSueldo() in 
       C:\xampp\htdocs\empleados.php:24 Stack trace: #0 
       C:\xampp\htdocs\empleados.php(46): Comerciante->__construct('Elver', 
       'Apellido', 23) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(57): 
        include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in 
        C:\xampp\htdocs\empleados.php on line 24
```

Comment: Edita y agrega el mensaje de error completo por favor

Comment: Tienes que llamarla con $this->calculasueldo(). Por otra parte, ese método hace referencia a self::horasExtra, cuando debería ser $this->horasExtra... Revisa los conceptos de self y this, que parece que los estás mezclando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debiese quedar asi la linea del error :

```
$this->sueldo = $this->calculaSueldo();
```